# How to evaluate limits of inverse trigonometric functions without L'Hospital and series expansion?

Tags: limits, analysis, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I am studying limits and how to evaluate them without using l'Hospital Rule or series expansion.
Most of them aren't that hard, there are some common trick to do, but I have issues when I face limits of some not-so-common functions such as inverse trigonometric functions.

An example of such a function is this:

[image]

And also:

[image]

I have no idea how to even approach such a limit so I would be happy if you could, besides just solving these two limits explain some approaches to evaluating limits with inverse trigonometric functions in general.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhôpital-rule-or-series-expansion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arctan(5x)}{\arctan(6x)} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arctan(5x)}{\arctan(6x)}\cdot\frac{6x}{5x}\cdot\frac56 = \frac56\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arctan(5x)}{5x}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{6x}{\arctan(6x)}=\frac56$$

---

Showing $\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\arctan u}{u}=1$

We know that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x }{ x } = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\tan x} = 1$$ $$\text{ Now substitute }\tan x =  u \implies x = \arctan u \text{ and as }  x\to 0 , u = \tan x \to 0 $$

Comment: Thank you, but how do I solve the second example?

Comment: @Matthew I'm working on that one. There must be some trick to evaluate it w/o L'           Hopital or expansion.

Comment: It didn't help me, but maybe you will find some use in this limit that looks very similar to the one I'm asking about: https://socratic.org/questions/how-can-i-evaluate-lim-x-0-sinx-x-x-3-without-using-l-hopital-s-rule.

Comment: @Matthew Yeah, I've come across that one, but here it'd become $\arctan 3x$

Comment: Someone commented the following link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion, where this exact limit is calculated. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice! It is useful for me too.

Comment: Could you please explain to me the last step he did, in which he went from 3L to 6L? How did he get that fraction inside tan^(-1) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105696/discussion-between-ak19-and-matthew).

Comment: $$\arctan(2x)- 2\arctan(x) = \arctan(2x) - \arctan(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}) = \arctan\left(\frac{2x-\frac{2x}{1-x^2}}{1+\frac{4x^2}{1-x^2}}\right) = \\ \arctan\left(\frac{2x-2x^3-2x}{1-x^2+4x^2}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{-2x^3}{1+3x^2}\right)  $$